# Fade out a div that is presented when exception is thown in php

Tags: php, html, jquery

I wish to have a div displaying an error message appear for a limited time after an exception is thrown in php. I've managed to do it when a form is submitted by using jQuery when checking if all fields are filled in:

HTML:

```
    <div id="error-message-box">
<h1 class ="error-headline">Error!</h1>
<p class ="error-text"><?php $errorMessage ?></p>
```

JS:

```
        $('form').submit(function () {
    var check = loginValidation($(this));
    if(check==false) {
        $("#error-message-box").fadeIn()
        $(".error-text").text("Fill in all the fields")
        $("#error-message-box").delay(7000).fadeOut();
    }
    return check;
});
```

This works alright, but I cannot figure out how to do something similar when an exception is thrown in php. In my php-file I have this:

```
    function displayError ($eMessage) {
$errorMessage = $eMessage;
```

}

```
    if(isset($_POST['log-in-btn'])) {
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
try {
    $sql=" SELECT * FROM User WHERE username ='".$username."' AND password= '".$password."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row["0"];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $row["1"];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row["2"];
    $_SESSION['surname'] = $row["3"];
    $_SESSION['email'] =$row["4"];
        }
}
else {
    throw new Exception("Username and password doesn't exsist");
}
}
catch (Exception $e){
    displayError($e->getMessage());
}
```

}

The only way way I can think of at the moment is to have an echo of the HTML-code of my error-message-box in the displayError-function, but then I don't know how to have it visible for a limited amount of time. Or, maybe somehow add a trigger or listener in jQuery to check if the div is visible so its triggered when the HTML-code is echoed, however I how no idea if that works. Any tips?

Comment: Please use password_hash, password_verify and prepared statements.. your way is a huge security hole.

Comment: Yes I'm aware! Planning to fix those sort of things later on - but thank you for the tips!

Comment: Are you using ajax/xhr for the login process or a normal html form?

Comment: I am using a normal html-form! It has a method = post which triggers the post-login-btn sequence